# How to specify duck typing (implicit interface) generics in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

For example

```
// Not valid Kotlin code.
fun <T : Summable> myFunction ...
```

`T : Summable` means any type `T` supports `+` operator, i.e. has a `.plus` method defined.

Comment: Even if it were possible, you don't have enough information in that declaration to use `.plus`. You'd have to specify what type `.plus` can take as well.

Comment: Closely related: "[Kotlin, generic operation on Number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40587118/90527)".

Answer (score 6):

There is no such feature in Kotlin, and it's not planned for a future release at this time.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the [DucKtypes](https://github.com/stangls/DucKtypes) project at GitHub, which allows for "static ducktyping". For example:

```
interface Summable { fun plus() }
object x { fun plus(){ println("plus") } } 
fun myFunction( s : Summable ){ s.plus() }
myFunction( x )
```

The project is still pretty new, but might soon have a gradle-plugin to automate code-generation.